# C# WPF Button.Click дополнительная информация

Tags: c#, wpf, события

Как мне передать некую дополнительную информацию, когда происходит событие клика на кнопку? К примеру, существует ListBox, который выводит информацию про товары (каждый товар обладает своим уникальным ключём) и есть для каждого товара кнопочка удаления его со списка. Но обработчик события клика этой кнопки только один, а товаров много. Значит нужно передать уникальный идентификатор товара обработчику события, для того, что бы он был усведомлён какой именно товар нужно удалить з базы данных. Каким образом это можно устроить? Или можно вместо кнопки что-то другое использовать?

Comment: Вас интересует более верный способ писать код или только заплатка к конкретной проблеме? Пробовали MVVM использовать?

Comment: `var product = (Product)((Button)sender).DataContext;`

Comment: @tym32167 Нет, не пробовал.

Comment: @tym32167 Я думал MVP универсальный.

Comment: Ничего универсального в программировании нет, каждый паттерн/алгоритм/подход/библиотека/фреймворк имеют свои назначения и хорошо решают конкретные задачи, а не общие/все возможные задачи.

Comment: То что я вам написал, попробовали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, работает.) Именно то, что мне нужно.